# How to "extend" RequestParam annotation on spring?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm building an API and I got to a point where a single method have a lot of annotations, e.g:

```
@Tag(name = "Messages")
@GetMapping("/{queue}/messages")
override fun getMessages(
    @PathVariable("queue") queue: String,
    @RequestParam("reason") reason: String?,
    @RequestParam("status", defaultValue = "PENDING") status: String,
    @RequestParam("start_date", required = true) @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm") startDate: LocalDateTime,
    @RequestParam("end_date", required = true) @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm") endDate: LocalDateTime,
    @PageableDefault(sort = ["createdAt"], direction = Sort.Direction.ASC) pageable: PageRequest,
): Page<DLQMessage> {
    return reason?.let {
        return messages.fromQueueByReason(queue, reason, startDate, endDate, pageable)
    } ?: messages.fromQueue(queue, status, startDate, endDate, pageable)
}
```

The amount of annotations on the method parameters is a bit odd for me, and I want to know if I can create an annotation "extension" to group the spring annotation in order to make the code cleaner, e.g

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FIELD)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
// @RequestParam("start_date", required = true)  
// @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
// ^ --> This annotation is not applicable to target 'annotation class'
annotation class MessageDateFilter()
```

If this is possible, I can use it on my controller method like this.

```
override fun getMessages(
    @MessageDateFilter startDate: LocalDateTime
)
```

How can I "extend" spring annotations?

Comment: Create an object to bind to. No need to extend anything.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using multiple annotations on each parameter, you can create a DTO (Data Transfer Object) that contains all the parameters you need in your method. You can then annotate the fields of this class.

```
    public class ClassName {
    @RequestParam("reason")
    private String reason;

    @RequestParam("status", defaultValue = "PENDING")
    private String status;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
    private LocalDateTime startDate;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
    private LocalDateTime endDate;

    // Getters and Setters
    }
```

Then you can add it to your controller:

```
@GetMapping("/{queue}/messages")
public Page<DLQMessage> getMessages(@PathVariable("queue") String queue, 
                                    ClassName params, 
                                    @PageableDefault(sort = ["createdAt"], direction = Sort.Direction.ASC) PageRequest pageable) {
    // Your logic here
}
```

Annotations cannot subclass one another, and annotation is not allowed to extend/implement any interfaces. Just use DTO pattern.
You also can use Lombok to make your DTO look cleaner.